# How can one import Vimeo methods in Angular 8 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, vimeo

In Angualr 8 app i have just imbedded a vimeo video and like to use its method, so I installed and imported vimeo but get an import error.

this is my `.ts`. Am i importing it wrong?

```js
import { Vimeo } from '@vimeo/player';
```

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', () => {
      console.log(this.isMobile);
      if (this.isMobile) {
        this.hideLogo = true;
      }
      console.log('played');
    });
```

the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this instead

```js
import * as Vimeo from '@vimeo/player';
```